# Plot Google Chart in PHP

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

i have three arrays:
`$array1`, `$array2` and `$array3`. Each having structures as(the count is different):

```
[{"year":"2016","month":"5","lab_id":"1","count":"19"},{"year":"2016","month":"6","lab_id":"1","count":"1"},{"year":"2016","month":"7","lab_id":"1","count":"8"}] 
[{"year":"2016","month":"5","lab_id":"1","count":"26"},{"year":"2016","month":"6","lab_id":"1","count":"34"},{"year":"2016","month":"7","lab_id":"1","count":"30"}]
```

I am trying to plot it in Google charts using the following code:

```
<?php
$rows = array();
 $flag = true;
 $table = array();
 $table['cols'] = array(
     array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string'),
     array('label' => '<15 min', 'type' => 'number'),
     array('label' => '>15 & <60', 'type' => 'number'),
     array('label' => '>60', 'type' => 'number'),
);
$rows = array();
 $allArray = array();
 array_push($allArray,$array1);
 array_push($allArray,$array2);
 array_push($allArray,$array3);
foreach($allArray as $dataArray) {
 $temp = array();
  foreach($dataArray as $item) {

       $temp[] = array('v' =>  "{$item["month"]}"."/"."{$item["year"]}");
       $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $item["count"]);

 }
   $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
?>
```

And the graph script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
          var options = {
          title: 'User Transaction Statistics',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

But I am not getting the expected chart. It should have dates (`5/2016`, `6/2016`, `7/2016`) as label and three line charts corresponding to `<15 min`, `>15 & <60` and `>60`.
  But instead I am getting this :

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdl7p.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the rows generated repeat the month column...
`{"c":[{"v":"5\/2016"},{"v":19},{"v":"6\/2016"},{"v":1},{"v":"7\/2016"},{"v":8}]}`

whereas all the values for a given month should be on the same row...
`{"c":[{"v":"5\/2016"},{"v":19},{"v":26},{"v":32}]}`

instead of combining all 3 arrays, access all three in the same loop sequence.
assuming they're all the same size, something like this should work...

**PHP**

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
  array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '5', 'lab_id' => '1', 'count' => '19'),
  array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '6', 'lab_id' => '1', 'count' => '1'),
  array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '7', 'lab_id' => '1', 'count' => '8')
);

$array2 = array(
  array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '5', 'lab_id' => '1', 'count' => '26'),
  array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '6', 'lab_id' => '1', 'count' => '34'),
  array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '7', 'lab_id' => '1', 'count' => '30')
);

$array3 = array(
  array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '5', 'lab_id' => '1', 'count' => '32'),
  array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '6', 'lab_id' => '1', 'count' => '45'),
  array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '7', 'lab_id' => '1', 'count' => '36')
);

$rows = array();
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
  array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string'),
  array('label' => '<15 min', 'type' => 'number'),
  array('label' => '>15 & <60', 'type' => 'number'),
  array('label' => '>60', 'type' => 'number'),
);
$rows = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++) {
  $rowLabel = array('v' =>  "{$array1[$i]["month"]}"."/"."{$array1[$i]["year"]}");
  $month1 = array('v' => (int) $array1[$i]["count"]);
  $month2 = array('v' => (int) $array2[$i]["count"]);
  $month3 = array('v' => (int) $array3[$i]["count"]);

  $temp = array(
    $rowLabel,
    $month1,
    $month2,
    $month3
  );

  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

?>
```

**HTML / JavaScript**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
    var options = {
      title: 'User Transaction Statistics',
      is3D: 'true',
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ajxe-6n0g) is a PHPFiddle I created to test with...

Comment: also recommend using `loader.js` vs. the older library `jsapi`